# how do i run a python script which takes one of the parameter as image(path) in windows-tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run a retrain.py inception.i already run the retrain.py i got image classifications.in try_retrain.py i need to pass one of the image as argument.The code will identify the type of image.Consider image1.jpg is the name of the image stored in Desktop which is to be classified with the help of the model which is already trained by retrain.py.

What i tried:

```
python try-retrain.py --image_path="./image1.jpg"
python try-retrain.py  ~/Desktop/image1.jpg
python try-retrain.py  --image_dir="./image1.jpg"
```

We already tried the same program execution in linux environment. we got output as required with the command

```
python try-retrain.py ~/Desktop/image1.jpg
```

Comment: What Error Message You Get in windows?

Comment: We are getting the error like File does not exits.

Comment: I will try once by coping the image and paste it in the terminal might be the path problem

Comment: Ofcourse its just path problem try using full path may your desktop have some some private permssion

Comment: If i drag and drop the image same code runs in windows also.It is file path error only.Thank you so much for your response.But the thing is in windows it uses backward slash(\).Ubuntu uses forward slash(/).

Comment: Ya I know The linux and window path is differ bcz of slash Happy Coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150716/discussion-between-ajay-pandya-and-manasa).

Comment: to avoid this slash problem you can use '//' instead of '/'